# Can't Open Marie Simulator

Tags: java, installation, marie

Mariesim.Jar file will not open. I have jdk and jre set up correctly. I have another computer that will run it fine. It opens the simulator with "Java SE Platform Binary." That option is not available with this computer. I have Jdk and jre 10.0.2. I'm on the website and my perception is that it is included?

Comment: I am still trying to open in. I still can't access it on this computer. What am I missing? I have been at this for a week.